# How to change view of number(CallIntent) to simple writing?

Tags: android

Now I have here code for callIntent and in my app is showing number and onClick it is calling, nothing wrong about this, all is fine, working. But I don't want that in app there will be seen number, instead I would like that there will be just simple view like "Call". But I have to setText to this numbers for callIntent. But How to change its view? Please can someone help me to do it.

```
public class Info extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.info);
        String[] tels = { "90 212 345 5555", "90 212 317 5330" };
    final TextView tel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tel);
    if (selected.equals("Istinye Park")) {
        tel.setText(tels[0]);
        infoText.setText(R.string.istinye);
    } else if (selected.equals("Kanyon Istanbul")) {
        tel.setText(tels[1]);
        infoText.setText(R.string.istinye);
    tel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+"
                    + tel.getText().toString().trim()));
            startActivity(callIntent);
        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: set "call" to your textView *tel.setText("Call")* and when set intentData (callIntent.setData(....) ) get the number from your array **tels** instead of getting it from the TextView

Comment: means for each one I have to make different callIntent?

Comment: You want to make the call only if *selected.equals("Kanyon Istanbul")* or also if *selected.equals("Istinye Park")*?

Comment: No, I want for both and both of them have different numbers. Like u see there is numbers string for each of them and my callIntent taking this text which I set for each of them and calling to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
public class Info extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.info);

    string[] tels = { "90 212 345 5555", "90 212 317 5330" };
    final TextView tel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tel);

    infoText.setText(R.string.istinye);
    tel.setText("Call");

    tel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String number;
            if (selected.equals("Istinye Park")) {
                number = tels[0];
            } else if (selected.equals("Kanyon Istanbul")) {
                number = tels[1];
            }

            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+"+ number));
            startActivity(callIntent);
        }
    });
 }
```

**Update** Solution with HashMap

```
public class Info extends ActionBarActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.info);

        final HashMap<String, String> myMap=new HashMap<String, String>();
        myMap.put("Istinye Park","90 212 345 5555");
        myMap.put("Kanyon Istanbul","90 212 317 5330");
        // add the rest of your items here

        final TextView tel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tel);
        infoText.setText(R.string.istinye);
        tel.setText("Call");

        tel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String number = myMap.get(selected);
                if(number!=null){
                   Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                   callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+"+ number));
                   startActivity(callIntent);
                }
            }
        });
 }
```

Comment: It is great solution, thanks, but I put here just two string items ("Istinye Park", "Kanyon Istanbul") to make code shorter, I mean actually I have really more, near to 35-40 items. Means 2 times if loop, it will be really more codes. I am searching for shorter solution. Just how to change this View of tel with shorter way. I heard about get/set Tag but I don't know how to do it...?

Comment: I've a better solution for that. Use a HashMap for your numbers and make the Name(Istinye Park, Kanyon Istanbul...) as key for your items, so you don"t need to loop all item just do *yourHashMap.get(selected);* and it will return the number of associated to this key